# sfdx force:org:list working with cmd but not working with powershell

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, powershell

I have weird issue.
i am trying to execute this command.

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

this command is working fine in cmd.exe but it fails in powershell

in cmd.exe

```
== Orgs
     ALIAS  USERNAME                                   ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ─────  ─────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ─────────────────────
(U)  MyDomain  myAccount@Myaccont.com  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Connected

No active scratch orgs found. Specify --all to see all scratch orgs

C:\Users\webapp>
```

but in powershell
C:\Users\webapp>sfdx force:org:list

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XX.XX.XX:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
  port: 443
}
WARNING: Starting in API version 52, the JSON output of this command no longer returns the property connectedStatus for scratch orgs.
=== Orgs
     ALIAS  USERNAME                                   ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ─────  ─────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
 (U)  MyDomain  myAccount@Myaccont.com                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  ETIMEDOUT

No active scratch orgs found. Specify --all to see all scratch orgs

C:\Users\webapp>
```

i am working behind a proxy. otherwise i cant access the internet.
but i applied this command.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000
```

any idea why this happen ?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). What version of Salesforce CLI do you have installed?

Comment: @Moonpie.i am using sfdx-cli/7.120.0 win32-x64 node-v14.18.0

Comment: Environment variables not picked up so you need to set them explicitly if you are doing from vscode you can choose what kind of terminal you want. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1